# Undefined method for nil class in Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations, rails-models

So, I have a `Game` class that can have many `Versions`, and each `Version` can have many `GameStats`. I have my Each `Version` `belongs_to` a `Game`, and each `GameStat` `belongs_to` a `Version` and `has_one` `Game` through the `Versions`. In my tests, when I test for response to the `game` and `version` objects, and for object equality, those tests pass, but when I try to reference the object by calling `@stats.game`, I get a `#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'game' for nil:NilClass>`. I'm very confused here, because I could do a `@stats.game` in the rails console, but it somehow does not exist in the test.

The relevant model code is here:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :platforms, through: :versions
  has_many :game_stats, class_name: 'GameStats', through: :versions

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class GameStats < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :version

  has_one :game, through: :version

  validates :version_id, presence: true
end

class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :platform

  has_many :game_stats, class_name: 'GameStats'

  validates :game_id, presence: true
  validates :platform_id, presence: true
end
```

And my RSpec file (the relevant parts) is like so:

```
describe GameStats do
  let!(:game) { FactoryGirl.create(:game) }
  let!(:platform) { FactoryGirl.create(:platform) }
  let!(:version) { FactoryGirl.create(:version, game: game, platform: platform) }

  before do
    @stats = FactoryGirl.create(:game_stats, version: version)
  end

  subject { @stats }

  ....

  it { should respond_to(:version) }
  it { should respond_to(:game) }

  its(:version) { should eq version }
  its(:game) { should eq game }

  ...

  describe "2 different days stats should have the same game" do
    before do
      @stats.save
      @another_stats = FactoryGirl.create(:game_daily_stats, version: version, datestamp: Date.yesterday)
      @another_stats.save
    end
    expect(@another_stats.game).to eq @stats.game
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error is happening?

I'm on Rails 4.0.0, with Ruby 2.0.0-p247, using RSpec-rails 2.14.0, factory_girl_rails 4.2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace:

```
expect(@another_stats.game).to eq @stats.game
```

with:

```
it 'description' do
  expect(@another_stats.game).to eq @stats.game
end
```

BTW, use `let` instead of instance variables

Comment: Thank you. That worked, I can't believe I missed that out. That was rather careless of me.

Comment: all rspec users do this one day or another ;)